# Quadratic sieve: How do I determine which factorization to use? Running into problems deciding which value to take $\mod n$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, sieve-theory

I'm trying to factor $n=1829$ by hand with a quadratic sieve, using the factor base $B=\{-1,2,3,5,7,11,13\}$. Now, by computing various squares of the form $(\lfloor \sqrt(in) \rfloor + j)^2 \mod n$, I've obtained the following:

\begin{align*}
42^2 &\equiv -65 &&= -1*5*13 \\
43^2 &\equiv 20 &&= 2^2*5 \\
61^2 &\equiv 63 &&= 3^2*7 \\
85^2 &\equiv -91 &&= -1*7*13
\end{align*}
Putting these together, I get that 
$$(42*43*61*85)^2 \equiv (-1*2*3*5*7*13)^2 \mod n$$
and I'm able to proceed with the factorization.

My question is the following:
When I originally reduce the squares modulo $n$, how do I know which value to take? For example, I took $42^2 \equiv -65$ instead of the more obvious choice of $1764$. Similarly for $85^2 \equiv -91$. Of course, there are an infinite number of possible choices for which value each of these can take. How do I know which ones will help me a priori?

Comment: As you see, obtaining the relation of two squares congruent mod $n$ depends on having a sufficient number of factorizations over a comparably small number of distinct "primes" (noting that you've taken advantage of using $-1$).  An obvious strategy is to retain those factorizations that involve small primes, since that restricts the size of the set of factors in a heuristic way.  In practice the quadratic sieve might be implemented to keep not only those very smooth factorizations (all small factors) but some that involve one or two larger primes (hoping they appear again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the lifted representatives to factor into small primes (and a unit $\pm1$) only, which is most likely for numbers with small absolute value.
Therefore you choose the representative with smallest absolute value (which is unique for odd $n$).

If that does not work, simply forget that one and look at squares of other numbers, again the representatives with smallest absolute value. Those are (roughly) similar in magnitude, about some small multiple of $\sqrt{n}$, instead of being guaranteed to be at least about $n$ if you'd stick to the old square and just choose another representative.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you! I suppose this is more of a general strategy than a hard and fast rule though, right? Like, you could probably cook up an example where a larger absolute value might work where a smaller one wouldn't?

Comment: @Alex: Yes. In this particular question, this is justified by the sheer size difference; remember that $n$ is typically large enough that factoring it requires the quadratic sieve; so you cannot afford trying to factor other representatives than the smallest-abs ones. That said, when optimizing such sieves, implementors tend to become even more picky. Like, not even considering remainders divisible by $2^3$ but not $2^4$ etc. Those are just heuristics about what is most likely helpful enough that it's worth the effort of being considered a possible relation.